# Не определяется местоположение при помощи yandex maps api на мобильных

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите пожалуйста,определяю местоположение посетителя при помощи js и yandex maps api.
Когда заходишь на сайт с ПК местоположение определяется, с телефона не определяется. При этом при заходе с телефона другие элемента сайта,зависящие от js работают, например слайдер,всплывающие окна,табы.
В чем может быть проблема?Почему не определяется местоположение при заходе с телефона?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init() {
        ymaps.geolocation.get({provider: "yandex"})
            .then(function (res) {
                var g = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                sessionStorage.setItem('city', g.getLocalities()[0]);
                $(".user-city").html(g.getLocalities()[0]);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Не удалось установить местоположение', err);
            });
    }
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("city")) {
        $(".user-city").html(sessionStorage.getItem("city"));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Карт определяет местоположение двумя способами:

- по IP-адресу: провайдер `yandex`
- средствами устройства через API браузера: провайдер `browser`

В API доступен также провайдер геолокации `auto`, который пробует определить местоположение обоими способами, а потом выбирает наиболее точный результат из двух.

В вашем коде используется определение местоположения только по IP-адресу и по какой-то причине на мобильном устройстве этот метод не срабатывает, например, IP-адрес недоступен на уровне кода API.

Попробуйте включить провайдер `auto` или пробуйте определить местоположение средствами браузера в случае ошибки геолокации по IP.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Поменял способ определения на auto но не помогло, с мобильного телефона все также не определяется местоположение.
Подскажите,в чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: @GregoryTer может быть в браузере мобильного устройства для этого хоста запрещена геолокация. Попробуйте почистить разрешения (попробовать другой мобильный браузер с того же устройства?) или вот на этом примере поотлаживаться: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation

Comment: В другом браузере также не работает.
Перешел по вашей ссылке с мобильного устройства,страница запрашивает разрешение на определение местоположения устройства,после этого местоположение определяется корректно. На моем же сайте такого разрешения не запрашивается. Быть может в этом проблема?

Comment: этот запрос делает сам браузер единожды для каждого нового домена; ответ записывается в настройки браузера и повторно разрешение на геолокацию уже не запрашивается. Видимо, для вашего сайта уже когда-то было выбрано "блокировать". Как писала выше, попробуйте почистить настройки разрешений браузера. Это уже вне логики API Карт.

Comment: Спасибо!Проблема решена.
Не знаю, что именно помогло, но заработало. Поменял provider на  auto, немного переписал скрипт, и почистил настройки и кеш браузера.